# Transfer variables from html to another html with JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

Is there a change to transfer javaScript variables from html page to another? I have multiple html 'sub pages' and one 'main page' and i have to make these sub pages to communicate with the main page by sending their variables to it. However the sub pages use same variable names and somehow i need to calculate the overall amount in the main page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or you can use single javaScript file included in page header and then load all your sub pages via AJAX ([jQuery.get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)). This way all your javaScript variables will stay intact, holding values in memory all the time.

Just structure your javaScript in [module](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html) to prevent global namespace pollution.
And make your control variables **objects** rather than **primitive types** (string, number...) because you can update references easily in events, functions... Primitive types goes by value, meaning javaScript creates copy in current scope.

Comment: How can I sort the variables with .get? for me it returns the whole sourcecode, not single variables

Comment: You can't. Don't mix javaScript and HTML (and CSS). When you call $.get('url') it returns sub-page html than you decide what to do with it. What exactly do you have in you variables you wanna save into variable?

Comment: well, in my sub pages i have an interactive form that is generated by the users selections. The form calculates a price of a product depending of the form selections, however the user can add multiple items in his 'cart' which are these sub pages i use as iframe. in the main page I have to calculate the total price of the products. Here's my orginal question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15616983/independently-working-div-in-jquery

Comment: Huh lots of Forms an IFrames :) Why not use HTML list (<ul><li>...<ul>) as a Cart? Are you getting item price from server-side?

Comment: Yes, the price calculation happens in server-side. I would rather use some other method but iframe, but my form that is generated by the user's selection breaks when there are multiple forms with same field id's, if the user adds a new product to the cart. (new div with the same html content)

Comment: Id should be unique (only one per page). When user adds same item again to cart just change quantity for that item.

Comment: The problem is that every item is unique, as you have to input model, dimensions and materials of it before the price can be calculated.

Answer (score 0):

No. JavaScript variables are always scoped to the current page. You must use some kind of server state, if you want to save state between pages.

Comment: What kind of server side system do you prefer? is there a change to move data between these html docs but database? or can i use PHP sessions for example?

Comment: really depends on the overall design of your application. Do you want to keep the items in your cart when the user walks away and comes back at a later point in time and logs in again? then you have to use a database. Or do you want to keep the items around for a single HTTP user session? Then you could use PHP sessions for example.